# How to save an audio file (.m4a format) in a database and access in ios?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, audio-recording

I'm a newbie to iOS, and I'm trying to write an app that records m4a files. In fact, this app will have as many files as user wants to record, I wanted to put it into a database using sqlite3 only (no core data), and when the user clicks on the name of the recorded file, the app accesses the database and loads the file. It would be really appreciated if anyone respond to this and help out.

Waiting for the answer !!

Comment: I don't understand, you need help to use sqlite? Or to record the file, store it in sqlite and display all the sounds into a Table?

Comment: People, he's a newbie, if you down vote without saying why, your down vote is useless ><

Comment: i have done the recording part, now i want to save it in a database (using sqlite3) and display all the saved files in a table n play the files as the user taps on the saved file.. (just as the italk recorder app)

Comment: Place the files in a database will not be goed for performance, you'd better just save the file to disk and store the path to the file in the database. Also please try to build this your self before just asking for help, Now it really looks like a code request which is frowned upon.

Comment: I am trying from many days and not able to do so i asked for help. Right now I have stored the files in documents directory but dont know how to store the path to the file in the database.

Comment: Add the code where you store the file in the directory please. And do you know how to use sqlite in Obj-C?

Comment: no i dont know much about sqlite, right now i just want to create a database and need to learn that stuff..

i have done this :

filename = @"Music/nnnn";
        filename = [filename stringByAppendingString:@(filecounter).stringValue];
        filename = [filename stringByAppendingString:@".m4a"];

NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],filename,nil];

 NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation of CoreData, it tells you that storing large objects (like mp4 files) in a database is a very, very, very bad idea. You should store them as files; feel free to store their relative paths in a database, but not the files. Just don't do it.

Comment: Alright !! How to store as files and their relative paths in a database ?? I have just started learning ios so plz explain.. And NO core data, puhlease..